# I am working on a New user registration form that only contains of 3 fields, Username, password and confirm password

Tags: c#, authentication, parameter-passing, sql-insert, password-confirmation

I am working on a user registration form containing only 3 fields Username,password and confirm password. But when i insert data, if password is mismatching, the exception appears form mismatch but on clicking  OK, the data is inserted into db.
what should i do that it only insert on matching password

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         conn.Open();
         OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
         command.Connection = conn;
         string query = "INSERT INTO Users (username,newpassword)values('" + txt_newusr.Text + "','" + txt_password.Text + "')";
         if (txt_password.Text == "" || txt_cnfpw.Text == "")
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Please enter values");
             return;
         }
         if (txt_password.Text != txt_cnfpw.Text)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Password confirm password are not matching");
             txt_cnfpw.Focus();
         }
         MessageBox.Show(query);
         command.CommandText = query;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Record Saved successfully");
         conn.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Place the `return;` after `txt_cnfpw.Focus();` and see what is happening

Comment: @sujithkarivelil it catches the error exception that connection is not closed

Comment: Indeed, a return is missing after the focus, so, the query is executed. And **you should validate the data before doing anything with the query**, that said, place validation before the try, and *it will better in a distinct method*.

Comment: **SQL INJECTION WARNING** --- Your query is totally vulnerable for attacks. Please use Parameters like @sujithkarivelil proposed.

Comment: @OlivierRogier thank u so much for ur valued opinion  <3 now i get where i was making mistakes

Comment: Indeed, you should use named parameters (or ?) with Parameters.Add

Answer (score 1):

You should change it like that

```
if (txt_password.Text == txt_cnfpw.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(query);
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Saved successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do lots of corrections to make this work properly, Corrections like the following:

- Make use of parameterized queries instead for concatenated queries to avoid injection
- Process insert only after client-side validations(empty check password match etc)
- Make use of using for managing connections and commands

I have added an example below, please have a look

```
try
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Users (username,newpassword)values(@username,@newpassword)";
    bool CanInsertNewUser = true;
    if (txt_newusr.Text=="" || txt_password.Text == "" || txt_cnfpw.Text == "")
    {
        CanInsertNewUser = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter values");
    }
    if (txt_password.Text != txt_cnfpw.Text)
    {
        CanInsertNewUser = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Password confirm password are not matching");
        txt_cnfpw.Focus();
    }
    if (CanInsertNewUser)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("GiveYourConnectionStringHere"))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_newusr.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@newpassword", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_password.Text;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OLEDB issues : " + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both the success and failure cases you are attempting to commit the transaction.
Save statements should only be executed if the password is matching. Move the save statements inside the success block as follows.

```
if (txt_password.Text == txt_cnfpw.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(query);
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Saved successfully");
}  
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password confirm password are not matching");
    txt_cnfpw.Focus();
}
```

Comment: what if `txt_password.Text` and `txt_cnfpw.Text` are empty? can `txt_newusr.Text` have empty values?>

Comment: @sujit karivelil You have to return there itself in order to avoid the execution in case of empty values

Comment: @sujithkarivelil i think it was placing save statement outside the success block as sukanya told 
thanx to all of you who helped me <3
love from Pakistan

Comment: @MuhammadAli: Lol... Include an empty check for `txt_newusr.Text` as well to avoid empty user name

Comment: @Sukanya: I Know that. I was trying to help you to improve your answer as it was your first answer(I guess based on your reputation) in this forum. Appreciate the helping mind and hearty welcome

Comment: @sujithkarivelil thank u so much brother now i get what u was exactly telling .